# Python: How to get a value from randomly selected key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do here is to get a random choice from a list

```
races = ['Dragonborn', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Gnome', 'Half-Elf', 'Halfling', 'Half-Orc', 'Human', 'Tiefling']
races_choice = random.choice(races)
```

and then use that random choice from the list to look at keys in a separate dictionary

```
subraces = {
'Dwarf': ['Hill Dwarf', 'Mountain Dwarf'],
'Elf': ['High Elf', 'Wood Elf', 'Dark Elf'], 
'Halfling': ['Lightfoot', 'Stout'], 
'Gnome': ['Forest Gnome', 'Rock Gnome'],
}
```

and if that key matches the random choice, print a random value from that key.

I've tried a few things, but what I'm currently on is this:

```
if races_choice == subraces.keys():
    print(random.choice(subraces.values[subraces.keys]))
```

But this returns nothing. I'm a bit at a loss for how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: `races_choice ` is a single string, `subraces.keys()` is a list of dictionary keys, so therefore `races_choice == subraces.keys()` can never be true. What about `subraces.get(races_choice)` or `subraces[races_choice]`?

Comment: @G.Anderson Not list but view.

Comment: @KellyBundy a good point well made.

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you for explaining this to me. I'm super new and I did spend a lot of time trying to figure this out before posting it. So, again, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.get` on the dictionary.

```
DEFAULT_VALUE = "default value"
subraces = {
       'Dwarf': ['Hill Dwarf', 'Mountain Dwarf'],
       'Elf': ['High Elf', 'Wood Elf', 'Dark Elf'], 
       'Halfling': ['Lightfoot', 'Stout'], 
       'Gnome': ['Forest Gnome', 'Rock Gnome'],
}

races = ['Dragonborn', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Gnome', 'Half-Elf', 
        'Halfling', 
        'Half-Orc', 'Human', 'Tiefling']

races_choice = random.choice(races)
subrace_options = subraces.get(races_choice, DEFAULT_VALUE)
if subrace_options != DEFAULT_VALUE:
    index = random.randint(0, (len(subrace_options) - 1))
    print(subrace_options[index])
else: 
    print("No subrace for specified race")
```

This will yield the name of a subrace from a given race e.g. for `Dwarf` the output will be a random entry in the list i.e. `Hill Dwarf`.

The string value in the `.get` is the default value which will be assigned if the key (the random choice) cannot be found in your map of subraces.

Comment: Thank you so much. I genuinely spent hours trying to figure out how to do this before posting a question, and it turns out it was beyond simple.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can simply set a random int equivalent to the length of items accordingly to the key

```
import random

races = ['Dragonborn', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Gnome', 'Half-Elf', 'Halfling', 'Half-Orc', 'Human', 'Tiefling']

races_choice = random.choice(races)

subraces = {
'Dwarf': ['Hill Dwarf', 'Mountain Dwarf'],
'Elf': ['High Elf', 'Wood Elf', 'Dark Elf'],
'Halfling': ['Lightfoot', 'Stout'],
'Gnome': ['Forest Gnome', 'Rock Gnome']}

if races_choice in subraces:
    print(subraces[races_choice][random.randint(0, len(subraces[races_choice]) - 1)])  # -1 since lists starts from 0, not 1
else:
    print('"' + races_choice + '"', 'has no subraces')
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can try something like this:

```
from random import choice

print(choice(subraces.get(choice(races),[0])) or 'no matches')
```

Comment: Learning so much from all these answers. Thank you!!